# Singleton instantiated with this

Tags: java, singleton

I have an assignment for school where I have to spot patterns in a certain given project. All is well (well, relatively..) but it seems that most patterns I find are some sort of variation. The singleton I had to find is no different.

The code is given below. The strange thing about this is that this class does not seem to instantiate with the following constructor, as one would expect:

```
public Singleton() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

However, it is instatiated with `this` (as you can see in the original code below)? In my understanding this creates some sort of static singleton? I debugged and saw indeed that the first time the constructor is called by

```
Singleton x = new Singleton();
        x.Print();
```

, it is indeed null. And `this` is a Singleton instance. However, shouldn't there be

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

on top of the class instead of `singelton = this;`?

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton;

    public static Singleton getDefault() {
        return singleton;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public Singleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = this;
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm a singleton!");
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure it is indeed a singleton, it's just of the type I have never seen and I don't get reasoning behind it, that's what I'm basicly asking.

Comment: The point is not to modify the code; the point is to report as to why this is a singleton. It's clearly a singleton, but I'm confused about how this is realised with ``this`.

Comment: You create the instance in the moment you call the constructor, so `this` refers to your instance (it's common practice to assign member variables their values with e.g. `this.name = name`). Since singleton is not initialized yet it will be `null` and you can assign it with your instance. After that further initializations of course have `singleton != null`, so no new assignmet will be done.

This way is however not really clean, since a call of `Singleton.getDefault().Print();` will result in a nullPointerException.

Comment: It's not a singleton at all, since anyone can call the constructor and get a new instance. It's crappy code, and nothing else. Certainly not a design pattern. Doesn't make any sense. I really hope the teacher's intention is to make you spot the crappyness of this code, and not to let you believe it's actually a singleton.

Comment: Well, the class in question here is part of an eclipse plugin (Graphical Editing Framework). I've been inspecting the code and from what I can tell it's actually never used.. All I can see being used is `Singleton.class` being passed to other methods from which I can't make anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has *not* followed the `Singleton` pattern. I have shown below a class following the Singleton pattern. `this` refers to the current object instance. When you initialize the singleton reference with `this` inside constructor, it calls the default (no-args) constructor and assigns it back to the `this` reference and then it is assigned to `singleton` class member variable

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton;

    public static Singleton getDefault() {
        if (singleton == null)
            singleton = new Singleton();
        return singleton;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    private Singleton() {
        System.out.println(singleton);
        if (singleton == null) {
                /*this will call a default constructor
                 *and instantiate Singleton object
                 */
            singleton = this;
        }
    }

    public void Print() {
        System.out.println("I'm a singleton!");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getDefault();
        System.out.println(singleton.Print());
    }
}
```

Hope you can understand!

Answer (score 1):

There is generally two approaches to creating a Singleton class, both are based on keeping the constructor private.
The first approach:

```
public class Singleton
{
  public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

  private Singleton{...}
}
```

You create an instance like this:  Singleton single = Singleton.INSTANCE;

The second approach:

```
public class Singleton
{
  private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

  private Singleton(){...}

  public static Singleton getInstance(){ return INSTANCE; }

}
```

In this case, you create an instance like this:  Singleton single = Singleton.getInstance();
The getInstance() method is then regarded as a public factory method.

As you can see, in both cases the new keyword is definitely used to create a single instance of the class, but because of the pattern used, there can only be one instance and no more.  You don't need to use the "this" keyword.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the meaning or `this`. `this` is not instantiating the class, `this` references the newly created instance. Then whenever someone calls your constructor a new instance is created (and returned) no matter you store in `private static Singleton singleton;` or not.
As well said @dic19 you must make your constructor `private` for preventing more than one instance to exist.
If the point is not to modify the code as you said, then the point is to report that this class is NOT a singleton.

You can check debugging:

```
    Singleton x = new Singleton();
    Singleton x1 = new Singleton();
    Singleton x2 = new Singleton();
```

You will see all three are different instances, being `Singleton.getDefault()` simply the first you created.

Answer (score 0):

If we use `singletone` we do not need to create instance for use. Because when we are creating `singletone` then we are creating `new instance` if not created. 
Take a look of below code :

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleton;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getSingleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Singleton();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public void testSingleTone(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Singleton.getSingleton().testSingleTone();
    }
}
```